# Bash - Find and replace regex with another string

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, sed

I have the following string `libVersion = '1.23.45.6'` and I need to replace `1.23.45.6` with `1.23.45.7`.

Obviously the version could be any number with similar format (it does not have to be 4 numbers).

I tried to use the following but doesn't work

`echo "libVersion = '1.23.45.6'" |sed "s/([0-9\.]+)/1.23.45.7/g"`

Comment: `echo "libVersion = '1.23.45.6'" |sed "s/[0-9.]\+/1.23.45.7/g"`

Comment: or `echo "libVersion = '1.23.45.6'" |sed "s/'[^']*'/'1.23.45.7'/g"`

Comment: Bingo!!! Please put it in the answer so I can mark as the correct answer

Comment: Actually, you can use the `E` option with your regex ([`sed -E "s/([0-9.]+)/1.23.45.7/"`](https://ideone.com/WclXrt)). But `/g` is redundant if you want to replace once and the `(...)` is redundant since you are not using the captured value. I'd use [`sed -E "s/[0-9.]+/1.23.45.7/"`](https://ideone.com/K6B1Xq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic sed, ie sed without any arguments uses `BRE` (Basic Regular Expression). In `BRE`, you have to escape `+`, to bring the power of regex `+` which repeats the previous token one or more times, likewise for the capturing groups `\(regex\)`

```
echo "libVersion = '1.23.45.6'" | sed "s/[0-9.]\+/1.23.45.7/"
```

You may also use a negated char class to replace all the chars exists within single quotes.

```
echo "libVersion = '1.23.45.6'" | sed "s/'[^']*'/'1.23.45.7'/"
```

Since the replacement should occur only one time, you don't need a `g` global modifier.

Comment: @wiktor you kidding me :P